# {on the margins of} to modify histories or communities?and pls explain the grammatical structure of the following sentence.

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammar

### The Sinophone world refers to Sinitic-language cultures and communities born of colonial and postcolonial histories **on the margins of geopolitical nation-states all across the world.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand "on the margins of ... across the world" to modify "Sinitic-language cultures and communities", so that we could rephrase the sentence so:

> The Sinophone world refers to Sinitic-language cultures and
>   communities on the margins of geopolitical nation-states all across
>   the world, cultures and communities which were born of colonial and
>   postcolonial histories.

If we take "margins" literally, it would mean "border regions"..."in the border regions of nation-states".

It we take "margins" figuratively, it could refer to

a) where and how underprivileged and at-risk populations live, as in "on the margins of society", that is, "*life on the edge*".

or possibly

b) communities  *on the **verge** of becoming* nation-states

though it would be an odd use if that were the case, and in that case, "on the margins of ... across the world" could modify **histories**.

If we look at US history, we can see that many Sinitic-language speakers came to the US in the 19th century to work under very harsh and difficult conditions, and so the figurative meaning, "on the margins of society", daily life as lived by underprivileged populations, is the most likely meaning.